# How do you group similar n-th child selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I sum these css selectors together?

```
td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(5) {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

I thought of something like

```
td:nth-child(1,4,5) {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

but this doesnt work. Is there a way to condense this?

Comment: I can only think about classes, but than you are losing `nth-child` functionality

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/nnzym84n/

Comment: What is the rule that governs the selection of the first, fourth, and fifth children?

Comment: @torazaburo I just want to select those.

Comment: What is the total number of children?

Comment: Could be 5, could be 13, could be 129491974177. Does that matter? I just needed a shorter version of saying "child a,b,c" with a,b and c completely random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a `an+b` formula to target them (which is the case in your particular example), then the code you wrote is the shortest version.

If you wish to simplify the CSS code, you could switch to classes... that however will make your HTML less clean.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is `an+b` the only formula or are there other ways to frame something?

Comment: That's the only one (expect for `odd` and `even`)